# Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

G'Day.
I want to iterate over a bunch of JSON objects and turn them into React Elements.  The objects look like this

```
                                "fields":
                                    [
                                        {   
                                            key: "testname",
                                            "name": "testname",
                                            "altName": "",
                                            "visible": true,
                                            "groupVisibility": "public",
                                            "type": "text",
                                            "component": "input",
                                            "label": "Test Smart Input",
                                            "placeholder": "Some default Value",
                                            "required": "required",
                                            "validated": false,
                                            "data": []
                                        },
                                        {   
                                            key: "password",
                                            "name": "password",
                                            "altName": "",
                                            "visible": true,
                                            "groupVisibility": "public",
                                            "type": "password",
                                            "component": "input",
                                            "label": "Test Smart Input",
                                            "placeholder": "Password",
                                            "required": "required",
                                            "validated": false,
                                            "data": []
                                        }
                                    ]
```

And the code that iterates over them is quite simple. Such:

```
//--------------------
formFields(fieldsIn) {


    const fieldsOut = [];                                           // ARRAY of FORM ELEMENTS to return
    console.log('doin fields');
    for (var fieldIn in fieldsIn) {                                 // array of FORM ELEMENT descriptions in JSON
        console.log(fieldIn);
        let field = React.createElement(SmartRender,                // go build the React Element 
                                        fieldIn,
                                        null);                      // lowest level, no children, data is in props     
        console.log('doin fields inside');
        fieldsOut.push(field);
    }
    return(fieldsOut);                                              // this ARRAY is the children of each PAGE
}
```

And I get the error
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
Any hints?
Cheers

I changed the code to do this.

```
//--------------------
formFields(fieldsIn) {


    const fieldsOut = [];                                           // ARRAY of FORM ELEMENTS to return
    console.log('doin fields');
    for (var fieldIn in fieldsIn) {                                 // array of FORM ELEMENT descriptions in JSON
        console.log(fieldIn);
        let field = React.createElement(SmartRender,                // go build the React Element 
                                        {key: fieldsIn[fieldIn].name, fieldIn},
                                        null);                      // lowest level, no children, data is in props     
        console.log('doin fields inside');
        fieldsOut.push(field);
    }
    return(fieldsOut);                                              // this ARRAY is the children of each PAGE
}
```

And I get the same error.  I don't understand why!
Fixed!  Thanks for the help.

Here is the code.

```
    //--------------------
    formFields(fieldsIn) {


        const fieldsOut = [];                                           // ARRAY of FORM ELEMENTS to return
        for (var fieldIn in fieldsIn) {                                 // array of FORM ELEMENT descriptions in JSON
            console.log(fieldIn);
            let field = React.createElement(SmartRender,                // go build the React Element 
                                            {key: fieldsIn[fieldIn].key, fieldIn},
                                            null);                      // lowest level, no children, data is in props     
            fieldsOut.push(field);
        }
        return(fieldsOut);                                              // this ARRAY is the children of each PAGE
    }


    //----------------------
    pages(pagesIn, format) {

        // I tried to do this in JSX, but no syntax I wrestled with would
        // allow me to access the childred when building this with the
        // BABEL transpiler.  Same goes for the METHOD just above, items().
        //
        // This method returns an array of pages this are React elements
        // this are treated as children by the smartForm.

        const pagesOut = [];                                            // array of pages to build and return
        let Section = {};                                               // Component to fire in the build
        switch(format) {
            case 'accordion': {
                Section = AccordionSection;
                break;
            }
            case 'workflow': {
                Section = null;                                         // I haven't written this yet
                break;
            }
            case 'simple': {
                Section = null;                                         // I haven't written this yet
                break;
            }
        }

        for (var pageIn in pagesIn) {                                   // pages, any format, any number 1..N
            let children = this.formFields(pagesIn[pageIn].fields);     // 1..N fields, we don't know beforehand 
            let page = React.createElement( Section, 
                                            pagesIn[pageIn].props, 
                                            children);
            pagesOut.push(page);
        }
        return(pagesOut);                                               // this ARRAY is the children of each FORM
    }



    //--------
    render() {

        let formIn  = this.props.form;                                  // JSON description of FORM
        let formOut = null;                                             // contructed REACT/Javascript form


        switch (formIn.format) {                                        // what type of operation is this
            case 'accordion': {                                         // Accordion in a FORM, OK
                let children = this.pages(formIn.pages,
                                          formIn.format);               // build the children
                formOut = React.createElement(Accordion,                // construct the parent with ALL nested CHILDREN after
                                            {key: formIn.formName},     // just a unique key 
                                            children);                  // N ACCORDION pages, N2 input fields
                break;
            }
            case 'workflow': {
                let children = this.pages(formIn.pages,                 // build the children
                                          formIn.format);               // build the children
                formOut = React.createElement(Workflow,                 // and create the complex sheet element
                                            { key: formIn.formName},
                                            children);                  // N SLIDING pages, N2 input fields
                break;
            }
            case 'simple': {
                let children = this.pages(formIn.pages,                 // build the children
                                          formIn.format);               // build the children
                formOut = React.createElement(Simple,
                                            { key: formIn.formName},
                                            children);                  // One page, N input fields
            break;
            }
        }

        return(
                <div>
                    <h2>SmartForm Parser</h2>
                    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                    {formOut}
                </div>
        );
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
export default SmartForm;

//-----------------   EOF -------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique key prop to your React element.

According to the **[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)**:

> `Keys` help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity.
>
> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies
>   a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your
>   data as keys
>
> When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the
>   item index as a key as a last resort

You can do it like

```
for (var fieldIn in fieldsIn) {                                 // array of FORM ELEMENT descriptions in JSON
        console.log(fieldIn);
        let field = React.createElement(SmartRender,                // go build the React Element 
                                        {key: fieldsIn[fieldIn].key, fieldIn},
                                        null);                      // lowest level, no children, data is in props     
        console.log('doin fields inside');
        fieldsOut.push(field);
    }
```

Why are keys necessary?

By default, when recursing on the children of a DOM node, React just iterates over both lists of children at the same time and generates a mutation whenever there’s a difference.

For example, when adding an element at the end of the children, converting between these two trees works well:

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

React will match the two `<li>first</li>` trees, match the two `<li>second</li>` trees, and then insert the `<li>third</li>` tree.

If you implement it naively, inserting an element at the beginning has worse performance. For example, converting between these two trees works poorly.

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

That is where keys come in handy.

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect my code change.  I get the same error....  I am missing something here!

Comment: Is the key in your json object unique, Please check if `fieldsIn[fieldIn].key` is giving you the correct key value, I added it assuming that it is what you index

Comment: Thanks mate.  My whole fieldsIn structure is undefined!  I'll post here when I get it sorted.