# Why my this.state is null?

Tags: json, reactjs, websocket, state, render

I'm new with React and i'm trying to render a json from a websocket.

Right now i'm able to get the json from the websocket using this :

```
 componentWillMount() {
    this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://10.77.0.79:1234')
    this.ws.onmessage = e => this.setState({data: Object.values((e.data))})
    this.ws.onerror = e => this.setState({ error: 'WebSocket error' })
    this.ws.onclose = e => !e.wasClean && this.setState({ error: `WebSocket error: ${e.code} ${e.reason}` })
  }
```

And then i need to map this json, right now i'm using this:

```
 render() {
  // this is my json from websocket
      var json2 = {"Auth":{"status":"true","user":"gesplan","pass":"root"}}

       var arr = [];
  Object.keys(json2).forEach(function(key) {
      arr.push(json2[key]);
    });

    return <ul>{arr.map(item => <MyAppChild key={item.status} label={item.status} value={item.user} pass={item.pass}  />)} {this.state.data} </ul>;

  }
}

class MyAppChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li>{this.props.label + " - " + this.props.value + this.props.pass  } </li>;
  }
}
```

With this i can render the values of the var json2.

How can i do it with my this.state.data? when i change json2 for this.state.data it return a null, but how can the state be null if i am rendering it normally?

Comment: set the initial state data to an empty array and then you probably won't face this issue

Comment: like this? this.state = {
  data : []
    }

Comment: I'm getting this error now :  Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error

Comment: here : Object.keys(this.state.data).forEach(function(key) {
      arr.push(this.state.data[key]);
    });

Comment: this is the right way to set the function right?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/loop-through-an-object-in-react/43721237#43721237

Comment: I'm reading it now, will try to use like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your initial state to an empty array first. Append data when new data comes in:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://10.77.0.79:1234')
    this.ws.onmessage = e => this.setState({
      data: [].concat(this.state.data, JSON.parse(e.data).Auth)
    })
    this.ws.onerror = e => this.setState({ error: 'WebSocket error' })
    this.ws.onclose = e => !e.wasClean && this.setState({ error: `WebSocket error: ${e.code} ${e.reason}` })
}

render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.state.data.map(item =>
        <MyAppChild key={item.status} label={item.status} value={item.user} pass={item.pass}  />)
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: @LucioZenir Updated

Comment: now i'm getting a warning : Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
And it renders : undefined - undefinedundefined

Comment: I'm thinking you may not want to use `Object.values(e.data)`. Try my updated edit.

Comment: i'm using your updated edit, still return undefined = (

Comment: Check this for the keys error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322401/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop/47322462#47322462

Comment: @LucioZenir Add `console.log(this.state.data)` above the return in the `render()` function, and ignore Shubham's suggestion for now. The issue is the array you're filling (Trying to understand what `e.data` is, and how it's looking when we append it to the array)

Comment: ["{"Auth":{"status":"true","user":"gesplan","pass":"root"}}"] this is the console return

Comment: Based on your `<MyAppChild>` props, we need the array to look like: `[{"status":"true","user":"gesplan","pass":"root"}]`, so we need to parse the json string, and return the Auth key. But do look into @ShubhamKhatri's post about key's. `item.status` does not appear to be unique.

Comment: IT WORKS, THANKS MAN, thank you both, i will study this for now and try to improve on react

Comment: One more doubt, in this case i have a json like this :  
["{"Auth":{"status":"true","user":"gesplan","pass":"root"}}"‌​]
I can get the values from status, user and pass.

But if i have a json like this :
["{"Auth":[{"status":"true","user":"gesplan","pass":"root","nvl":{"obj":"text"}}]}"]
How can i get the value from obj? since he is inside another level of the json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163348/discussion-between-frankerz-and-lucio-zenir).