# Using .map() to generate elements with Refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a best way to go about using .map() to output elements with refs?

I'm doing this so I can track the elements (generated from state) for collision detection in an endless runner style game (without canvas).

I’ve tried 3 different approaches and matter what I do I seem to get `ref=ref()` when it should be `ref=“tango”` (as per the state). Image here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Za1.png

> EDIT: for others in future, I have since learned that `ref=ref()` is expected behaviour to indicate a callback is associated with it, instead of the old way of showing the actual ref.

Code being used-

```
this.state = {
   people: {
      tango: { height: 10, weight: 200 },
      cash: { height: 20, weight: 300 }
   }
};
...
outputStatePeople(key) {
    return(<span className="db" key={key} ref={key}>name: {key}</span>)
}
...
render() { return (
<div>
    {Object.keys(this.state.people).map(key => this.outputStatePeople(key))}
</div>
)}
```

The above use a function to generate dom, but this also happens if outputting inline html and when using a component.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ref` needs to be a function https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Neoares ty for helping! still no luck - https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/MQdxJq
same output of `ref=ref()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `function for a ref` and store the refs in the class variable object like

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     people: {
        tango: { height: 10, weight: 200 },
        cash: { height: 20, weight: 300 }
     }
  };
  this.domRefs = {};
}
outputStatePeople(key) {
  return (
     <span className="db" key={key} ref={(ref) => {this.domRefs[key] = ref}}>
        name: {key}, height: {this.state.people[key].height}
     </span>
  );
 }
```

You can read more about Refs and Dom [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've tried that here - https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/KQLJOy
but no luck, still the same issue `ref=ref()`

Comment: @Ash, refs won't give you the refs, but if you console.log(this.domRefs), you will see all the components there

Comment: Ah i see, thanks mate, that seems to be working now!
I also found I can use a string ref like `key={ref}` without the need for the `domRefs` object. Would that be a good idea? code here - https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/xYNvXg?editors=0011

Comment: React docs advice you on not using string refs, also they are deprecated. As per the key, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322401/warning-each-child-in-an-array-or-iterator-should-have-a-unique-key-prop/47322462#47322462

Comment: The key to React component must be unique within an iterator.

Comment: ah cool, the key will be unique as its a unique name, from the state object. that ok?

Comment: @Ash yes that is what you must use